# to find the string(e.g name) which ends with % in sql

Tags: sql, sql-like

I want a sql query which will give the first name that ends with '%'

Please help.

Comment: Show the query you used, and how it didn't work?

Comment: Anyway see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you want ends or contains? (The title says one thing, and the body something else...)

Comment: sorry, typing mistake...corrected.

Comment: I am using oracle sql developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most versions of SQL support `ESCAPE`:

```
where lastname like '%/%' escape '/'
```

Other options are:

- Look for the character using a function such as `instr()`, `position()`, `charindex()`.
- Use a regular expression.
- Use `right()` or a substring function.

For instance:

```
where right(lastname, 1) = '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`%` is used to match any character(s) in a string when using the `LIKE` operator.  For example, `LIKE '%aniel'` would match `Daniel`, `Nathanial`, `My name is Daniel`, etc.

You have to escape it using the proper methods for your RDBMS.  In T-SQL, you could do that like so:

```
WHERE LastName LIKE '%\%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: can you please explain me this-->  '%\%' ESCAPE '\'

Comment: `ESCAPE` specifies what you want to use as the escape character - % is normally used for something else, so we're saying that we want a % followed by a \ to be treated as a regular %.

Answer (score 0):

if  lastname has'%'charecter use

```
select * from Members  where LastName like N'%[%]%'
```

Comment: Product specific answer. (And no dbms specified...)